# makefile not working with c++ zkcm-library - can't find mpfr-functions

Tags: c++, makefile, mpfr, zkcm

I have a makefile for use with some programs using the zkcm-library, including the following object line:

```
zkcm_c.o: zkcm_c.cpp zkcm_c.h config.h
     g++ -c zkcm_c.cpp -lgmp -lgmpxx -lmpfr
```

The compiler complains that there is an "undefined reference to '_*imp*_mpfr__inits2' " and the same for every use of mpfr-functions. The strange thing is, there are other objects in the makefile that uses mpfr-functions with no problem, e.g. the main program (first line):

```
SpMC: SpMC.cpp MCutility.h HPutility.h wfs.h MC_funcs.h $(ZKCMOBJECTS)  $(ZKCMHFILES)
     g++ SpMC.cpp -lgmp -lmpfr -lmpc -o SpMC $(ZKCMOBJECTS)
```

In both cases I have `#include<mpfr.h>` in the source and as you see link to it using `-lmpfr`.  Any ideas why this works for SpMC.cpp but not zkcm_c.cpp?

Comment: Seems that somehow mfpr functions got declared as `__declspec(dllimport)` in this particular case. `__imp_` stuff is in the import libraries.

Comment: I'd recommend to find `mpfr_inits` prototype in preprocessed output (`g++ -E SpMC.cpp`) and see whether it has __declspec. (I've looked into the header, it relies on `__GMP_DECLSPEC` which depends on `__GMP_LIBGMP_DLL` -- somehow it got defined.)

Comment: Thanks for helping out! But I'm still confused.. Do you mean you looked into zkcm_c.h or mpfr.h? In the former I can't find anything like this; in the latter there is " #if defined(__MPFR_WITHIN_MPFR) && __GMP_LIBGMP_DLL
# define __MPFR_DECLSPEC __GMP_DECLSPEC_EXPORT
#else
# define __MPFR_DECLSPEC __GMP_DECLSPEC
#endif"               should I change this somehow? It works with the other programs..

Comment: I meant `mpfr.h`. No idea what exactly you shoud change yet, but start with `g++ -E` output. Find mpfr_inits declaration. Does it have `__declspec`?

Comment: Using g++ -E I get a file SpMC containing   "__attribute__((__dllimport__)) void
  mpfr_inits (mpfr_ptr, ...) __attribute__ ((sentinel));"  there is no declspec. But SpMC.cpp is the file that is working, should I try the same with the problem file zkcm.c_cpp maybe?

Comment: Yeah, that's it. hm.. Try commenting out two lines starting with `# define __MPFR_DECLSPEC` in `mpfr.h`.

Comment: Hm, interesting. If I remove the line # define __MPFR_DECLSPEC __GMP_DECLSPEC_EXPORT I still get the errors I've described, if I remove # define __MPFR_DECLSPEC __GMP_DECLSPEC (or both lines) I don't get the mentioned errors but a bunch of new ones in mpfr.h and other files where I've used the mpfr library